# Should I use EventEmitter or shared Service in a reusable component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, oop, eventemitter, behaviorsubject

In Angular, I have a reusable `autocomplete` list and I need to pass the selected option to another component where this custom component is called. However, the custom component is not called directly and there is another component between them as shown below:

```
Component A:          -->      Component B:       -->      Component C:      
custom-autocomplete            modal-component             employee-component
```

Now there are 2 option I think:

**1.** I can pass the selected value from Component A to any component via a shared service. But I am not sure if it is a good idea to inject a service dependency to a reusable component.

**2.** I can pass the selected value to Component B via EventEmitter, but I do not know if it is possible or good idea to pass the emitted event from Component B to Component C. I think I can pass the received event and parameter as I pass via EventEmitter usually, but not sure if it is a good idea.

So, what should be done in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should use a shared service in which you should have `BehaviourSubject` type `observable`. So whenever user will select any value form `autocomplerte` so you can pass that selected option to your `BehaviourSubject` `observable` and then in your another `component` you can subscribe to that `BehaviourSubject`.

And if you want to use multiple reusable `autocomplete` in one `component` so while passing each `autcomplete's` selected value you can pass a property named `type` in which you will be sending your `autocomplete` type.

Like you have your function like this

```
passDataToAnotherComponent(selectedOption: any, type: string){
   this.dataService.passData({option : selectedOption, type: type})
}
```

So when you call your above function for city so you will be calling in your template like this

```
<select (change)="passDataToAnotherComponent($event, 'city')">
   <option>City 1</option>
   <option>City 2</option>
</select>

<select (change)="passDataToAnotherComponent($event, 'department')">
   <option>department 1</option>
   <option>department 2</option>
</select>
```

And then in your receiving component just do like this

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.dataService.behaviourSubjectObservableVariable.subscribe(data => {
       if(type === 'city){
            // do somehting
       }
       if(type === 'department){
            // do somehting
       }
   })
}
```

Just gave a rough example to make you understand.

Comment: Yes, I normally share data using `BehaviourSubject observable` in a service and I think there is not another option for this scenario to pass data from dumb (presentationl) component to another sibling component. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that's correct. Because using this option you can pass your data to even unrelated components regardless of `parent-child` relationship

Comment: Another question is that, assume that there are 3 reusable autocomplete on `employee-component`, that means the dumb reusable autocomplete is called three time (let's say city, department, profession). In that case I am not sure if I have to create 3 subject behaviour to receive all of three autocompletes correctly. Or what should I do in order to use the same reusable component multiple times at time time (in the same component). Because when I change City, it may be possible to change other 2 autocomplete values automatically. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any idea about my last comment regarding to using the same dumb component multiple times in teh same component?

Comment: So you want to receive all 3 reusable component's selected values in one component?

Comment: Yes, but without not affecting one to another after one of their selected value changes.

Comment: So you can pass some property in your data that you pass into your BehaviourSubject to idenitfy that whether it is city , depart or profession.